# How to Connect multiple(more than 2)android devices by bluetooth

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect multiple android devices, but it is working for 2 devices **(Server < -- > Client communication)**, I want to achieve multiple client connected to server at a time all, i.e One android device as a server and other as clients.

I am following this code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510591/8647372

but its not getting connected, getting this error

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Please help, trying from long time...

Comment: use this instead ,https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library

Comment: also tried it, but not working. can connect only 2 device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3)

Comment: actually my main focus is on connecting multiple devices at once. simultaneously