# How to get bluetooth device's mac-address onclick?

Tags: android

I'm tring to get mac-address of devices (photo/vol + button) when I click on it.

dream would be something like this :

```
on"vol+"clicklistener{
var=get.bluetoothDeviceMacAddress
}

if (var == aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa){ action1}
if (var == bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb){ action2}
```

thanks

Mick

Comment: please define what you're trying to do and try adding what you've tried.

Comment: Hi, I've got 2 bluetooth photo button that emulate the vol+ button. I'd like to know which one is triggered. I can list all bluetooth mac-addresses but can not find last triggered... context is a game where you need to buzz to answer question. bluetooth button will be the buzzer. thanks

Comment: i think you are trying to listen for data from multiple devices simultaneously, you can try reading this, i'm not if it can help you, but you can try understanding it a little.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497103/multi-connection-via-bluetooth-in-android

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try...